# Django Programming Error for checkbox

Tags: django, django-forms

I keep getting this error on form submission:

```
Exception Type:     ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    column "location_completed" of relation "core_dailyprogress" does not exist
```

My model looks likes this:

```
class DailyProgress(BaseModel):
    location_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
```

My form is as follows:

```
class DailyProgressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    location_completed = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=False)

    class Meta:
        model = DailyProgress
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
          'location_completed': forms.CheckboxInput(),
        }
```

Finally, my template is:

```
<label>{{ form.location_completed }} Location Completed</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically that error indicates a Database issue. By chance have you by chance recently added location_completed without a migration? There's a weird issue with Postges on Django 1.8+ that sometimes fails to alter tables after migrations. Are you able to access location_completed from the shell?

Also, I believe you can simplify your form code to:

```
class DailyProgressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    location_completed = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=False)

    class Meta:
        model = DailyProgress
```

Since CheckboxInput is the default widget for forms.BooleanField.

Comment: I had to run a pending migration.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine. You should probably check to see if this database table has this column (as the error message implies) or if you have migrations that have not yet run.